# Old files after upgrading to ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, backup, apache2

I upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 12.04 LTS using ISO image, and after finishing upgrading I found out that `/var/www` folder was deleted. I know I was stupid to believe that it was upgrade and all my software and file will be there, I should've take a backup before upgrading. Is there any chance that I can have my projects back? Is there a special folder where ubuntu stores old files something similar to windows. Old as applied to windows (sorry for mentioning windows here :-P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes our last resource is to use some recovery tool like [photorec](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/testdisk) or foremost.

*Photorec is easier to use:*

1) [Install testdisk](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/testdisk),

2) Open a terminal,

3) Run `sudo photorec` and answer the questions.

---

*Foremost lets you choose which files you want to recover:*

1) [Install foremost](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/foremost),

2) Open a terminal,

3) The command is something like `sudo foremost -d -vqT -o /media/sda3/foremost -t jpg,ole,zip -i /dev/sdb1`

The output folder comes after the option `-o` and the input comes after `-i`.

The recovered files chose here are jpg, ole (= docx odt), zip.

Comment: thanx for your help! That was life saver..

Comment: I know how it feels to lost important files... Glad to help.